# how to install postgresql on centos 6.2

Tags: centos6, postgresql, installation

1. In centos there is repos very old version. so we go to [lastest files postgresql](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php)
2. Copy the download location and curl the rpm into the server

   curl -O https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
3. Install the rpm

   rpm -ivh pgdg*
4. Install the server, It will also install 2 other packages.

   yum install postgresql96-server
5. Initialize DB

   su - postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/data"
6. Start server

   su - postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -l logfile start"

Comment: I dont know what will happen if server reboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS 6.2 You should be able to auto start your postgres server by using chkconfig.  you should be able to see what the service name is with something like

```
chkconfig --list | grep post
```

which on a C6 system I have to hand shows

```
...
postgresql      0:off   1:off   2:off    3:off    4:off    5:off    6:off
```

Your installation from the vendor repository would likely look like

```
...
postgresql-9.6      0:off   1:off   2:off    3:off    4:off    5:off    6:off
```

(disabled at all run levels). To enable it using chkconfig

```
chkconfig postgresql-9.6 on
chkconfig --list | grep post
...
postgresql-9.6  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

(enabled at run levels 2-5 off otherwise)

Comment: do you know why installation is very complicated and undocumented. I looked 2 official documentation from vendors, and 4 blogs, but I need to combine and find which works.  
Always a prompt show me there is error without solution or reason like my customers: they say "site is not working".  Yes he didnt opened computer, or he is in flight mode, etc. 
that's the path where it goes reverse direction of success.